# how to prevent spring application context from being loaded over and over during unit tests

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I have a spring-based Java EE webapplication. I am testing my "repositories" which are just data access objects (DAOs) using junit. I use maven to build and test my project. An example of a unit test I have is shown below:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/business-objects.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class JpaUserRepositoryTests {
 @AutoWired
 UserRepository userRepository;

 @Test
 @Transactional
 public void testCreate() {
  boolean result = userRepository.create(new User("name","pass"));
  Assert.assertTrue(result);
 }
}
```

my maven-surefire-plugin configuration looks like the following.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.13</version>
 <configuration>
  <includes>
   <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
  </includes>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My problem is that I have multiple repository tests and each time I run "mvn clean test", for each repository test class, the spring application context is loaded over and over. Is there any way to configure my tests so that the Spring application context is loaded only once for all my repository tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set option *forkMode=once* (currently, with version 2.15, this option already defaults to "once". I don't know since when this is the case but I know it was "always" in earlier releases).

Comment: thanks, i think that was it. i simply updated from 2.13 to 2.15.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd, spring has a singleton which uses to cache the context for testing, as long as you use the same context configuration, spring will reuse the context ([see docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching))

The only two options that I can imagine, is that you're using an old version of spring which doesn't have this feature (I'm not sure when this feature was introduced, but I think sometime around version 2.5.x)

The other alternative is that your project inherits from a maven pom which configures surefire to use [forkMode=always](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkMode) which will spawn a new jvm for each test class.

I don't know which other scenario might cause this... I hope the above helps.

Comment: i am using spring-framework.version=3.2.2.RELEASE and spring-data-jpa.version=1.3.1.RELEASE.